# GUI or CLI ? i installed Modelica in the cloud

Tags: user-interface, command-line-interface, modelica

so i installed Modelica in a cloud server and im currently trying to decide if i should use a command-line interface or graphical user interface?

Any advice?

Thanks
Osman

Comment: [Modelica](https://modelica.org/) is a [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelica). Did you also install a Modelica compiler? Which one? And does your cloud even allow graphical user interfaces?

Comment: For experienced users, maybe CLI is a good option you could run the simulation faster with less memory, but for newbies, GUI is more suitable. And by using drag and drop, you could save a lot of work when using Modelica. I think most users choose GUI instead of CLI.

Comment: Modelica is a modelling language, actually. It is not obvious what you actually installed.